# Wordpress https to http 301 not working

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, https

Google has indexed some of the pages on a new Wordpress site as https so I am attempting to initiate a site-wide redirect on all https requests using; which from research looks like the correct approach.

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
#RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

However, when I subsequently visit any page using https://example.com I am still getting a site security error, i.e. no redirect is taking place.

Answer (score 0):

SSL is negotiated before any HTTP requests take place. There for the error will always show before any redirection occurs. I recently found this out myself.